# Scala memory use

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I've been trying out Scala in a pet project recently and noticed that the following code snippet was eating up memory (I call this method a lot):

```
private[this] def isConsistent(startLang2: Int, lengthLang2: Int, 
    startLang1: Int, lengthLang1: Int,
    lang2FinalAlignments: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Int]]): Boolean = {

    (startLang2 to (startLang2 + lengthLang2)) foreach {
      i =>
        val valueSeq = lang2FinalAlignments(i)
        if (valueSeq.size == 0 || valueSeq.exists { value => value < startLang1 || value > (startLang1 + lengthLang1) })
          false
    }
    true
}
```

When I changed the 'false' to 'return false' the situation seems to have resolved itself:

```
private[this] def isConsistent(startLang2: Int, lengthLang2: Int, 
    startLang1: Int, lengthLang1: Int,
    lang2FinalAlignments: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Int]]): Boolean = {

    (startLang2 to (startLang2 + lengthLang2)) foreach {
      i =>
        val valueSeq = lang2FinalAlignments(i)
        if (valueSeq.size == 0 || valueSeq.exists { value => value < startLang1 || value > (startLang1 + lengthLang1) })
          return false
    }
    true
}
```

When I think about it snippet #2 makes sense with regards to how I expect/want the method to work. Could someone please explain to me what the first snippet is doing?

Comment: The first snippet does something different. It's a constant `true`.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala  But you already know how to use `exists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what `foreach` does:

```
def foreach[U](f: Elem => U): Unit
```

So it runs `f` on every element of the collection and discards its result - it doesn't care about the return type of `f`.

In your case when you call

```
... foreach {
  i => {
    ...
    if (...)
      false
  }
true
```

the body of the function return `false` if the condition is satisfied and `Unit` otherwise. Their common supertype is `Any`, so the function passed to `foreach` is of type `Int => Any`. It's result is discarded and *you traverse the whole collection*. (Try giving an explicit type such as `foreach[Any]` or `foreach[Boolean]`.)

In the second snippet the situation is very different:

```
... foreach {
  i => {
    ...
    if (...)
      return false
  }
true
```

Here `foreach` traverses the range *only until the condition is satisfied* and then `return` escapes the `foreach` execution and makes the main function exit.