# how to break out of a loop in scala worksheet?

Tags: scala

I have a continuous loop in scala worksheet represented by the rotating bar.

```
object sheet1 {
   def loop() : Int = loop
   /   <-- rotating bar
   loop()
}
```

Is there a way to break out of the loop?

**NOTE**:

I am asking how to terminate execution within Scala **[Worksheet](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started)**.  I am NOT asking how to terminate out of a loop in scala.  This question I am asking is definitely **NOT** the same as this: [How do I break out of a loop in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I break out of a loop in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the marked question; I know it seems like 'breaking out of a loop in Scala' seems to indicate it's a dupe, but it's a different thing from what is being asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press the escape key (or any key for that matter) to kill the worksheet. It's on the [Getting Started documentation, under Verbose Output](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started)