# Exit for loop as soon as condition satisfied

Tags: scala

The following code hangs the repl:

```
(
  for {
    i <- 1 to 1000000
    j <- 2 to 1000000
    if i * i == j
  } yield i -> j
).take(1)
```

It seems the for expression is eagerly evaluated. Any solutions?

Comment: This could answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

I'd turn that into a stream:

```
(
    for {
        i <- Stream.range(1, 1000000)
        j <- Stream.range(2, 1000000)
        if i * i == j
    } yield i -> j
).take(1)
```

Comment: make that `Stream.range(1,10000000)` and you will avoid creating a gigantic `(1 to 1000000)` `Range` instance.