# only once in while loop with scala

Tags: scala, while-loop

I'm beginning with Scala. I have a program which have a method with a while loop which run until the program is not ended.

But for my test, I need to execute this method only once (or twice). In java, I would have used a mutable variable that I would have decremented in order to stop my treatment.

Maybe a condition inside my while loop that I override for my test.

```
def receive = {
    val iterator = stream.iterator()
    while (iterator.hasNext && my_condition()) {
        something_to_do
    }
}
```

I know it's a stupid question, but could you please advice me ?

Comment: There are multiple approaches to this problem.  It's been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
iterator.takeWhile(my_condition).foreach(something_to_do)
```

or:

```
iterator.take(n).foreach(something_to_do)
```

if you just want the first n entries.

Or, if `something_to_do` returns a result (rather than `Unit`), and you want to return an iterator of those results, you can use:

```
iterator.takeWhile(my_condition).map(something_to_do)
```

(or `.take(n).map(...)` )

Answer (score 2):

Consider this for comprehension,

```
for (_ <- iterator if my_condition()) something_to_do
```

where each iterated value is ignored (note `_`) and the todo part is invoked while the condition holds.

Answer (score 0):

I think an approach like the following is acceptable:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, Actor}

import scala.io.Source

object TestableActor {

  def props = Props(new TestableActor())

  def testProps = Props(new TestableActor(true))

  case class Message(stream: Stream)
}

class TestableActor(doOnce: Boolean = false) extends Actor {

  import TestableActor._

  val stream: Stream = ???

  def receive = {
    case Message(stream) =>
      val iterator = stream.iterator
      if(doOnce) {
        something_to_do
      } else {
        while (iterator.hasNext && my_condition()) {
          something_to_do
        }
      }
  }

  def my_condition(): Boolean = ???

  def something_to_do: Unit = ???
}
```

In your production code, use

```
context.actorOf(TestableActor.props)
```

In your test use

```
TestActorRef[TestableActor](TestableActor.testProps)
```

Comment: Why are Actors here? Are they necessary??

Comment: I thought because of your use of `receive` it was a snippet from an akka program.

Comment: If `receive` is simply a function with no parameters but with side effects, I suggest defining it as `receive() :Unit = {...}`  as per the style guide.