# Minimal Substring Satisfying a condition in scala

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop, break

I have a string, lets say `val mystr = "abcde"`, and I want to find the minimal substring of mystr which satisfies a given condition. I have to send a string to an external system, so the only way to do this is to iterate through the length of the string and make requests to the external system, and break when the response from the external system returns `true`

eg.

```
callExtSystemWith("a") //Returns false
callExtSystemWith("ab") //Returns false
callExtSystemWith("abc") //Returns true
```

Then my method should return "abc". I read [that breaks are not the scala way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala), so was wondering what is the scala way of achieving this?

Right now I have:

```
      for {end <- 1 to mystr.length)}{
        callExtSystemWith(mystr.substring(0,end))
        // I Want to break when this is true.
      }
```

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can use <s>`inits.toStream.reverse.drop(1)`</s> `(1 to s.length).map(s.take).toStream` to create a lazy stream with `a, ab, abc, abcd`.

Then filter those strings, so that only the ones for which `callExtSystemWith` returns true are left.

Then get the first string for which `callExtSystemWith` returns true. Because this is a lazy stream, no unecessary requests will be made to the server once the first match is found.

```
val s  = "abcdefgh"
val strs = (1 to s.length).map(s.take).toStream

strs.filter(callExtSystemWith).headOption match {
  case Some(s) => "found"
  case _ => "not found"
}
```

You can also use `find` instead of `filter` + `headOption`

Answer (score 1):

Quite often `break` can be replaced with `find` on some sequence

So here is another short solution for this problem:

```
def findSuitablePrefix(mystr: String): Option[String] = 
  (1 to mystr.length).view.map(mystr.substring(0, _)).find(callExtSystemWith)
```

`.view` makes the evaluation lazy to avoid creating extra substrings.
`.map` transforms the sequence of indexes into a sequence of substrings.
And `.find` "breaks" after the first element for which `callExtSystemWith` returns `true` is found.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala there are no normal breaks but there are other solutions. The one I like better is to create a function and force a **return** (instead of a normal break). Something like:

```
def callAndBreak(mystr:String) : Int = {

    for (end <- 1 to mystr.length) {
        if ( callExtSystemWith(mystr.substring(0,end)) ) return end
    }
    end
}
```

Here I return end but you can return anything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `return` or breaks, you could also use `foldLeft`:

```
val finalResult = (1 to mystr.length).foldLeft(false) { (result, end) => 
    if(!result) callExtSystemWith(mystr.substring(0, end)) else result
}
```

However, it is a bit hard to read, and will walk the entire length of the string.

Simple recursion might be a better way:

```
def go(s: String, end: Int): Boolean = {
  if(end >= s.length) false
  else {
    callExtSystemWith(s.substring(0, end)) || go(s, end + 1)
  }
}

go(mystr, 1)
```