# In Scala, how to abort the function?

Tags: scala

In java, **return** can abort function:

```
public void f(int a){
    if(a < 0){
        return;    //return keywords can abort the function
    }
    //TODO:
}
```

how to abort the function in scala?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I break out of a loop in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala)

Comment: You can still use `return` in Scala. Better would be to reorganize your code so it's not necessary though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, you just return from the function as normal:

```
def f(a: Int): Unit = { // Unit is Scala equivalent of void, except it's an actual type
  if (a < 0)
    () // the only value of type Unit
  else
    // TODO
}
```

You *can* use `return ()` to make the early return more explicit, but this shouldn't normally be done. See e.g. https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html.