# Break statement in Chisel

Tags: loops, break, chisel

Is there a **break** statement in Chisel so that we can break the **for** loop or is there any substitute for the same? If yes, can somebody please give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out [how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala). The short answer is no, scala does not support it directly, in Chisel itself the idea doesn't make a whole lot of sense with respect to generated hardware. If you feel that you still need it (after looking at the above link) it would be very important to understand the specifics of your use case.